# How do I get Chrome to play a WAV file?

Tags: google-chrome, download, audio

I'm using the following version of Chrome on Mac High Sierra

```
Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

When I download a .WAV file from my Gmail, I click on the file title as it appear at the lower left of my browser window.  However, instead of playing the file, Chrome just luanches a new window, set to "https://www.google.com".

How can I get Chrome to play my file instead of launching a new browser window?